# Nested ng-repeat doesn't work inside <input>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `$scope` param that looks like this:

```
$scope.filters = [{name: "Brands", brands: ['Brand1', 'Brand2', 'Brand3']}, 
                 {name: "Catalogs", brands: ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3']}];
```

In the html file I then try to display this as a list like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="filter in filters"><h3>{{filter.name}}</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="brand in filter.brands"> {{brand}}<br>
        </div>
```

The `filter.name` works, as I see `"Brands"` and `"Catalogs"`, but below them I see empty checkboxes. 
The only way to get it to work is to take the `ng-repeat` out of the input and put it outside in a label or something.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  $scope.filters = [{name: "Brands", brands: ['Brand1', 'Brand2', 'Brand3']}, 
                 {name: "Catalogs", brands: ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3']}];
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="filter in filters"><h3>{{filter.name}}</h3>
     <div  ng-repeat="brand in filter.brands">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="brands"> {{brand}}<br>
     </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: `brand` is not an object, so i'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: Yes, if I take the ng-repeat out of the input and put it outside, in a div, it works. But why won't it work inside the input?